# Verbs to use about someone who walks after someone they're chasing

Tags: word-choice, word-request, verbs

> Seeing the man, Kevin turns and runs. The man **walks** after him.

(The man starts chasing Kevin)

1. What could be some good verbs to use instead of **walks** in this context to imply walking quickly but not run?
2. I have found **strides**. Is that the best option you can think of as well?

Comment: The man **follows** Kevin. The man **hurries** after Kevin. What else did the thesaurus turn up?

Comment: You could say "The man *quickens his pace* to keep Kevin in view ".  It suggests that he speeds up but is not running to *keep pace* with Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you want to emphasize the way in which the follower proceeds, or the fact that he is chasing Kevin. To describe the manner of walking, "strides",  "steps", "trots", and "hurries" all could work. To focus on the goal of the movement such words as  "follows", "pursues", "chases", or "trails" might work.

Comment: I would think "trails" does the best to imply following at a slow pace.